# Microsoft Graph API subscription triggers same email with different IDs

Tags: microsoft-graph-mail

I have a weird hard-to-replicate issue with Graph API and Outlook subscription endpoints. A user is authorised in my app and subscription is created for `me/messages` with change type `created`.

Everything works fine in 99% of the cases, but once in a while the endpoint is triggered several times with the same email. There is no changes to the email or any other part of the request, except ID, even timestamp. I have no idea how to replicate it consistently and/or fix an issue. Is there any scenario where Graph API would send the same message twice with slightly different IDs? It looks like they are sequentially generated IDs too, as they differ by 1-3 characters in the very end.

Comment: This is a bug. I'll report this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd love to provide some consistent methodology to replicate it, but it's relatively rare, so the only debuggable trait is sequential id

Comment: Has it been fixed?